# Get DebugDraw working in JBox2D

Tags: android, jbox2d

I try to get the DebugDraw running in a simple Android JBox2D project.

I simply extend the DebugDraw like that and put some log output:

```
public class SimpleDebugView extends DebugDraw
{
    private static final String TAG = "SimpleDebugView";

    public SimpleDebugView() {
        super(new OBBViewportTransform());
    }

    @Override
    public void drawPoint(Vec2 argPoint, float argRadiusOnScreen, Color3f argColor) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Draw point");
    }

    @Override
    public void drawSolidPolygon(Vec2[] vertices, int vertexCount, Color3f color) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Draw solid polygon");
    }

    @Override
    public void drawCircle(Vec2 center, float radius, Color3f color) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Draw circle");
    }

    @Override
    public void drawSolidCircle(Vec2 center, float radius, Vec2 axis, Color3f color) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Draw solid circle");
    }

    @Override
    public void drawSegment(Vec2 p1, Vec2 p2, Color3f color) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Draw segment");
    }

    @Override
    public void drawTransform(Transform xf) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Draw transform");
    }

    @Override
    public void drawString(float x, float y, String s, Color3f color) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Draw string");
    }
}
```

I use the new debug class like that:

```
[...]
        mWorld = new World(gravity);
        mWorld.setAllowSleep(true);
        SimpleDebugView simpleDebugDraw = new SimpleDebugView();
        simpleDebugDraw.setFlags(DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | DebugDraw.e_aabbBit | DebugDraw.e_pairBit | DebugDraw.e_centerOfMassBit | DebugDraw.e_jointBit | DebugDraw.e_dynamicTreeBit);
        mWorld.setDebugDraw(simpleDebugDraw);

[...]
```

Afterwards I create bodies and start the physics simulation.

My simulation works, I render my stuff based on the simulation on a canvas.

But when I want to use DebugDraw (since this sometimes makes the modelling of the physical world a bit easier to debug), this doesn't seem to work. The Log output is not appearing, and when debugging, also the breakpoint don't get hit in my SimpleDebugView. So it seems the methods are not called at all. Am I using DebugDraw wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I need to tell my physic world that it should draw the debug via:

```
mWorld.drawDebugData();
```

So I called this directly after doing the step() and my methods get called.

Somehow I thought this would happen automatically when I attach a DebugDraw, but it wasn't.